# How do we need to argue in this step of the Itō-Lévy-Khintchine decomposition?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, levy-processes

Let

- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space;
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space;
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$;
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $E$-valued $\mathcal F$-adapted càdlàg Lévy process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$;
- $$\pi_t(B):=\sum_{\substack{s\in[0,\:t]\\\Delta X_s\ne0}}1_B\left(\Delta X_s(\omega)\right)=\left|\left\{s\in(0,t]:0\ne\Delta X_s\in B\right\}\right|$$ for $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ and $t\ge0$;
- $\lambda(B):=\operatorname E\left[\pi_1(B)\right]$ for $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ and $$\tilde\pi_t:=\pi_t-t\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$

Let $$f_B:=x1_B(x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E$$ for $B\subseteq E$ and $$X^B_t:=\int f_B\:{\rm d}\pi_t$$ and $$\tilde X^B_t:=\int f_B\:{\rm d}\tilde\pi_t$$ for $t\ge0$. Moreover, let $$U_\delta:=B_1(0)\setminus\overline B_\delta(0)=\{x\in E:\delta<\|x\|_E\le1\}$$ for $\delta\ge0$. We can easily show that $\left(\tilde X^{U_\delta}\right)_{\delta>0}$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal C(\infty)$ (see below) and hence there is an $E$-valued $\mathcal F$-adapted càdlàg process $Y$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$\left\|\tilde X^{U_\delta}\right\|_t\xrightarrow{\delta\to0+}0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0.$$

> **Question**: How can we show that $Y=X^{U_0}$?

My main problem is that it's (a priori) not clear to me that $$\int\|x\|_E\:{\rm d}\tilde\pi_t<\infty\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0.$$

---

$$\mathcal C(t):=\left\{X:(X_s)_{s\in[0,\:t]}\text{ is an }E\text{-valued }(\mathcal F_s)_{s\in[0,\:t]}\text{-adapted càdlàg process on }(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)\text{ with }\left\|X\right\|_t<\infty\right\}$$ equipped with $$\left\|X\right\|_t:=\left\|\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}\left\|X_s\right\|_E\right\|_{L^2(\operatorname P)}\;\;\;\text{for }X\in\mathcal C(t)$$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space for all $t\ge0$ and $$\mathcal C(\infty):=\left\{(X_t)_{t\ge0}:(X_s)_{s\in[0,\:t]}\in\mathcal C(t)\text{ for all }t\ge0\right\}$$ equipped with $\left\{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_t:t\ge0\right\}$ is a locally convex topological $\mathbb R$-vector space.